# Eiffel: how do I get the type of a particular operand of a procedure

Tags: introspection, eiffel

As I can see into the debugger it's possible to get the operands, and name of procedure, is there a way to get it?

- PROCEDURE=>operands returns a detachable that seems return the operands only when they have been setted into the agent
- Do I have pass through any REFLECTOR class because the PROCEDURE class doesn't have this function and in this case why?

[image]

Seems that estudio has access to informations as ROUTINE client don't have, why is he a privileged one? is he cheating?

Comment: if you evaluate `a_setter.open_operand_type (1)`  you will get the type id of the first open operand.
then using REFLECTOR will help getting the "human friendly" information.

for isntance `(create {REFLECTOR}).type_of_type (a_setter.open_operand_type (1))`

Comment: @Jocelyn I tried it too, but open_operand_type is not exported!!!! {NONE} in your perposition, I have a feature of qualified call is not available to client class.` and the operands which is the only feature available to get operands @runtime returns me Void :-( Check the ROUTINE class...

Comment: @Jocelyn how does the estudio watch compute the `agent` value? all informations are available there! but unavailable for a ROUTINE client. Sounds like estudio is a privileged one or is cheating!

Comment: I misunderstood your question, I thought you were asking about the debugger. And yes the debugger is not restricted by export clauses (hopefully).

Comment: Now, the ROUTINE class does not provide much, because the less is exposed, the better it is for evolution. Now, why do you need those information? For any very good reason, it may be possible to add new features to ROUTINE.

Comment: @Jocelyn so you dont see any way of accessing @ runtime the type of a parameter of a given routine?

Comment: I guess you can use `a_setter.generating_type`  that returns a TYPE, then use `generic_parameter_type`. And using the `ROUTINE.open_count` you can figure out the type of open and close operands.

Comment: When I started using design by contract, I stopped using a debugger.

Comment: @ctl-alt-deletor seems you reached the knowledge of guessing on first time what will be the behaviour of the method you use... still not my case!

Answer (score 2):

The following code demonstrates how to retrieve information about open argument types of a routine object:

```
        p: ROUTINE -- Routine object.
        t: TYPE [detachable ANY] -- Current open argument type.
    do
        p := agent (i: INTEGER; s: STRING)
            do
            end
        across
            1 |..| p.open_count as i
        loop
            t := p.generating_type.generic_parameter_type (1).generic_parameter_type (i.item)
            io.put_string (t.name)
            io.put_new_line
        end
```

For me, the code above prints

```
INTEGER_32
!STRING_8
```

Comments:

1. `p.open_count` gives the total number of open arguments.
2. `p.generating_type` retrieves the type of the routine object.
3. `p.generating_type.generic_parameter_type (1)` retrieves the type of the open arguments tuple object.
4. The final call to `generating_type` retrieves the type of the open argument with index `i.item`.